# Using chardet to detect encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I have already get the encoding of the file, but there is still error in encoding. I have no idea how to solve this problem. Could any one please help me?

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import chardet
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\beijing_20140101-20141231\beijing_20140101-20141231\beijingall')
file_chdir = os.getcwd()

filecsv_list = []
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(file_chdir):
    for file in files:
        if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.csv':
            filecsv_list.append(file)

data = pd.DataFrame()

for csv in filecsv_list:

    csvc=csv.encode()
    encoding=chardet.detect(csvc).get("encoding")
    print(encoding)

    b=pd.read_csv(csv,encoding=encoding,header=None,sep=',',engine='python')
```

**Error:** UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)

**Error in detail:**

[image: Error]

I have got it done. I did not notice that it could be a problem with **one of the files**. The real problem is that one of the files is garbled. Delete this file and tried encoding='utf8' help me solve this problem.

Comment: Please take a look at [this cool list of reasons why you should not post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 4):

`chardet` is passed sample data.  You are passing the filename string itself, encoded as UTF-8 (of which, ASCII is a subset), so you'll only ever get back `ascii` or `utf-8` as an answer.  Read the file, or at least a portion of it using binary mode, then pass that data to `chardet.detect()`.

```
for csv in filecsv_list:

    with open(csv,'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()  # or a chunk, f.read(1000000)
    encoding=chardet.detect(data).get("encoding")
    print(encoding)

    b=pd.read_csv(csv,encoding=encoding,header=None,sep=',',engine='python')
```

Comment: Exactly what worked for me, thanks. I experimented a bit and smaller chunk sizes would also give 'ascii' back, so minimum that gave proper (in my case) 'ISO-8859-1' was 100000.

Answer (score 2):

`chardet` clearly guesses wrong. Try to give it a sample from where the file actually differs from ASCII (apparently somewhere later in the file); but understand that `chardet` simply cannot always guess correctly. If you need the samples to be correctly processed, you really need to *know* their encoding.

Comment: Maybe also try https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy